Western Red Cedar (Thuja plicata) leaves - OK for putting on top of beds?
I have 3 basic beds in our yard (1) roses/hydrangeas, (2) blueberries and (3) dwarf Magnolias and a Lilac.
And one large Western Red Cedar that is shedding leaves - normal flagging. I usually sweep up the leaves on the sidewalk, driveway, roof and gutters and toss them in the yard waste bin. The ones in the (front) yard I just leave until early next fall.
In any of the beds mentioned above, will there be any benefit to covering them with these leaves?

Mulches help retain moisture in the soil and reduce weeds. Definitely there's benefit to placing these leaves as mulch.
There's some speculation that pine needles on the surface lead to acidic soils. I tried finding evidence of that in the past, but didn't see any firm evidence for that idea.

thank you, you also answered a question I had in mind that I didn't ask.

Arbs aren't pines... The idea that pines acidify the soil is a myth. For the science behind that statement, see https://extension.unh.edu/blog/2019/10/do-pine-trees-pine-needles-make-soil-more-acidic

@Jurp Podzols are real - Agathis australis (admittedly not "pine", but certainly a gymnosperm, within the Pinopsida) causes notable podzolization under the tree and only specifically under the tree, called a cup podzol. Agathis are much more acidic than most gymnosperms though.  Jongkind and Buurman 2006, seem to support this. But I agree not caused under most pines

Pretty much any organic mulch is a good mulch. I use my arbs' dropped leaves as a mulch with no problems.
